# Understanding raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I'm scraping twitter trying to get the friends/users being followed for a list of twitter users.  I'm using tweepy and python 3.6.5 on OSX 10.13.  An abbreviated code chunk  :

```
def get_friends_for_each_twitter_user(UserL=None, Name=None):
   .
   . # Auth keys and such
   .
   for user in UserL:  ### This is a list of USER class with the below fields ###
        ### Handle protected users ###
        if(user.protected == True):
            user.friendsL = "protected"
            continue
        screenNameL=[]
        friendIDL=[]
        friendL=[]
        friendScreenNameL=[]
        ### Get IDs of people that this user follows (i.e. 'friends') ###
        for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends_ids, screen_name=user.screenName).pages():
            friendIDL.extend(page)
            time.sleep(60)
        ## Loop through IDs, get user profile, keep only friends' screen name ###
        for i in range(0, len(friendIDL), 100):
            friendL.extend(api.lookup_users(user_ids=friendIDL[i:i+100]))
        ### Keep only screen name ###
        for friend in friendL:
            friendScreenNameL.append(friend._json['screen_name'])
        user.friendsL = friendScreenNameL
```

When I do this, after collecting the `friends` (i.e. profiles that the user follows) for about a dozen users, I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 357, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 190, in execute
    proxies=self.api.proxy)
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/pdb.py", line 1667, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/pdb.py", line 1548, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 434, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/myusername/Code/Python/hair_prod/src/main.py", line 170, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/myusername/Code/Python/hair_prod/src/main.py", line 141, in main
    get_friends_for_each_twitter_user(UserL=tresemmeUserL, Name="Tresemme")
  File "src/twitter_scraper.py", line 187, in get_friends_for_each_twitter_user
    friendL.extend(api.lookup_users(user_ids=friendIDL[i:i+100]))
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 336, in lookup_users
    return self._lookup_users(post_data=post_data)
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 250, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 192, in execute
    six.reraise(TweepError, TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 692, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 190, in execute
    proxies=self.api.proxy)
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
> /Users/myusername/.local/virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py(490)send()
-> raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
```

It appears that the errors occur on line `friendL.extend(api.lookup_users(user_ids=friendIDL[i:i+100]))` in the 
`get_friends_for_each_twitter_user()` function

**QUESTION** :

1. Why is this error occurring?
2. How do I avoid/work around it?

Comment: What is the `time.sleep(60)` for?

Comment: There are limits to how often you can query Twitter's API : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting.html  .  So the `time.sleep(60)` is to avoid reaching the time limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing with this for a while, I believe that this issue was caused by my network connection. When this happened, I was connected to my 5GHz wireless network.  When I connected to my 2.4GHz wireless network, these errors are less frequent. The proper thing to do in this situation is to handle the exception, wait a few seconds and try again.  Below is the appropriate code fragment:

```
def get_friends_for_each_twitter_user(UserL=None, Name=None):
    consumerKey =  #your value here
    consumerSecret = #your value here
    auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)  ### Supposedly faster
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)  ## Now I don't have to handle rate limiting myself

    for user in UserL:
        accountStatus = 'active'
        if(user.protected == True):
            user.friendsL = "protected"
            continue
        screenNameL=[]
        friendIDL=[]
        friendL=[]
        friendScreenNameL=[]
        #### TWITTER LIMITS US #####
        try :
            for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends_ids, screen_name=user.screenName).pages():
                friendIDL.extend(page)
        except tweepy.TweepError as error :
            if(error.__dict__['api_code'] == 34):
                accountStatus = 'dead'
                print("...{} is dead".format(user.screenName))
                continue
            else:
                raise

        for i in range(0, len(friendIDL), 100):
            ### This handles when exception occurs (probably due to connection issues)
            ### When exception occurs, sleeps then retries. I don't notice this error
            ### when I'm running on corporate Wifi, maybe my router just sucks
            while True:
                try :
                    friendL.extend(api.lookup_users(user_ids=friendIDL[i:i+100]))
                except tweepy.TweepError as error :
                    print("...Exception for {} : api_code {}".format(user.screenName,
                          error.__dict__['api_code']))
                    time.sleep(5)
                    continue
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

Any number of things could cause the error to appear, but if the cause is not permanent, then retrying an occasional failed API call could make the script work alright.

According to the [Tweepy docs](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#tweepy-api-twitter-api-wrapper) the API client constructor accepts a `retry_count` parameter which defaults to 0. Try setting `retry_count` to something above 0 and see if your script is able to complete successfully, something like this:

```
api = tweepy.api.API(..., retry_count=3)
```